# GridView Dropdownlist CSS First letter should be black color and remaining content should be in green color

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, gridview, html-select

how do i change the  color of a  first letter in dropdownlist inside gridview?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdAvailableRooms" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TESTDROPDOWN">
        <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomsCount" runat="server"    Width="120px"CssClass="GridTextinGreen" >     
         <asp:ListItem Value="0">Day</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">1 (USD 3510)</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="2">2 (SAR 7020)</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="3">3 (USD 8610)</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="4">4 (SAR 9050)</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    <Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

eg:
      1 (USD 3510)- the first letter '1' should be display in Black Color and the remaining content should be display in Green Color

Pls help me to apply these type of style.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS-selector for the first letter of an element is **:first-letter**.

For example, make the first letter of a paragraph red

```
p:first-letter { color: red; }
```

I'm not familiar with applying CSS styles to GridView, but this site seems useful http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx

edit:
As I said, I am not familiar with GridView. However, in the example given on the webpage provided they use

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAvailableRooms" runat="server"  
    CssClass="mGrid">
```

to assign a css class to the grid, and then in the css I guess you should do something like

```
.mGrid ul li:first-letter { color: red; }
```

Comment: @eevaa--> it works for paragraph<p>, how can i write it for Dropdownlist?

Comment: Please see my edited post. However, I am not even sure whether it is even possible to style GridView dropdown lists.